# How facebook shows the data to user in Android application?

Tags: android, logic

I am working on an application which shows so many data to user, but problem is that it takes too much time to load data even we are using paging too. I want to know how facebook shows the data to user. are they storing the data in database first and then display it to user? if yes then how they maintain the user activity on that.

Comment: use graph api of facebook sdk

Comment: Obviously they store the data in a database. Maybe they are using plain REST with authentication for displaying it in the mobile application. You can also compress it before sending to save bytes.